# Shadow drag effect on display in portrait mode

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

I just got a new AOC 27 inch pivot monitor (AOC Q2770PQU).

I've got it connected to a System 76 Galago Pro laptop with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4750HQ CPU @ 2.00GHz with Intel Haswell Mobile graphics. 16GB of Ram. It's running on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

**Problem:** When I rotate the monitor 90 degrees to portrait mode (changing the "rotation" setting in "System Settings => Displays" to clockwise), there is significant shadowing/drag effect when scrolling in Firefox and other applications. It seems like the refresh rate is very slow in that instance. Navigator is really bad when dragging windows. Interestingly, Chromium is fine.

When I connected the same monitor to a three year old Mac Mini (also has i7) and set it to portrait mode, there was no problem. The scrolling and window moving, etc. were fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too on a carbon X1 laptop. My setup was a bit different and I'm on 15.04 and I was rotating the other screen with xrandr, rather than using the system menu. Nonetheless, it also has a recent intel gpu (broadwell, but I don't think they're that different), so it's probably the same problem. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Install new (>= 2.99.917) xserver-xorg-video-intel. This is default on 15.04. It'll be more annoying to install on 14.04 (try ppas maybe?), but can be done.
2. Install kernel 4.0. The pkgs are at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/. More install info at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds. It seems that you have to install them with dpkg. Note that they're labelled "vivid." There are no 4.0 kernel builds labelled "trusty." I don't know if you will be able to install the 4.0 vivid builds with trusty. You can always upgrade. Or google for "How to install 4.0 on trusty." Or compile your own kernel.
3. Ensure that you are using SNA acceleration. SNA is the default, so if you haven't done anything fancy with xorg confs, you should be using it. I'd previously switched to UXA acceleration to deal with some issues that came up as a result of not having the fixes in the newer kernel and intel driver. Anyway, it didn't work for me until I'd switched back to SNA and restarted X.

Now my external monitor refreshes all fast and shit when I rotate it.